# DHCP & Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, dhcp

With a Windows workstation, the DHCP request is initialized by the workstation (the client).

So, is an "incoming rule" (UDP, ports 68/67) useful?

PS: I'm not sure how the Windows Firewall works, but with iptables Linux, I can only allow inbound "ESTABLISHED" communications.

Thank you for your help,

Niels

Comment: If you block all incoming UDP traffic, you have to create a rule to allow for UDP/68, the incoming DHCP replies. So yes, such an incoming rule would be useful. "Established" connections are TCP in whcih a three-way handshake is used to setup a connection. That concept does not exist with UDP traffic.

Comment: Ok thank you. However, I tested blocking all incoming traffic, and an "ipconfig / renew" worked well .

Comment: Are you sure it renewed its IP address? Possibly it was unable to get a new IP address and kept using its old address.

Comment: Yes. If I block all inbound/outbound traffic, no IPv4 adress is set. But if i block just inbound traffic, a IPv4 adresse is set.

Comment: When you say you tested blocking all incoming traffic, does that mean you disabled all the built-in rules, including the one for DHCP?